# How to open Bot Framework Emulator

Tags: botframework

What application should I use to open bot framework emulator. I have no idea. When I double click to open it, it asks me what app to use. I've tried every one I have(webstorm, internet, etc.). Any help would be GREATLY apreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bot Framework Emulator is an app by itself. If you are in Windows, please donwload the exe file from https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases, install it and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thankyou. It's working. When using it, I registered my bot, but I couldn't put my endpoint because it is an http, and it wants https. Do you know how to do that? I've heard of ngrok but don't know how to do it. Any help would be great.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered and add a new one with your new question. You don't need to register the bot to use it in the emulator. Just use the localhost address